# How to sort the gridview column in mixed integer and string using MatSort in Angular typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a mixed of integer and string in the result set or array. I want to sort the column using Mat-Sort-Header or custom function.

### Column Value

"1 of 10"
"4 of 25"
"2 of 7"
"10 of 8"
"3 of 6"
"11 of 7"

When i use the "mat-sort-header" on the grid view, it is sorting like as below, which is not the expect one.

### Column Value

"1 of 10"
"10 of 8"
"11 of 7"
"2 of 7"
"3 of 25"
"4 of 6"

I want to sort like this.

### Column Value

"1 of 10"
"2 of 7"
"3 of 25"
"4 of 6"
"10 of 8"
"11 of 7"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**parseInt** function is flexable

```js
console.log(
  ["1 of 10", "4 of 25", "2 of 7", "10 of 8", "3 of 6", "11 of 7"]
    .sort((a,b) => parseInt(a)-parseInt(b))
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am trying to apply your solution with my actual code.

Answer (score 1):

You can like this:

```
public getValue(item: string): number {
    const ofIndex = item.indexOf('of');
    const firstNumber = parseInt(item.slice(0, ofIndex - 1));
    const secondNumber = parseInt(item.slice(ofIndex + 3, item.length));

    return firstNumber / secondNumber;
}

public sortYourArray(yourArray: string[]): string[] {
    return yourArray.sort((a, b) => this.getvalue(a) - this.getValue(b));
}
```